# What do I need exactly to build an android web app

Tags: android

I'm looking to build an android web app for a website I'm currently coding so I need to know what technologies I'll need to get started. An example of the project I mean is the "stack exchange" android app. Thanks in advance

Comment: By "web app," I'm assuming you mean a standalone app that the user can use instead of visiting the website with a browser. Basically you just need a copy of Android Studio to get started. Start here: [http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Comment: Yea a bit....still learning tho'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need the Android SDK first of all ;) 
Than you can build a simple Activity with a WebView pointing to the URL of your website. And remember to add permissions for accessing to the Internet on your manifest. This is a very simple Activity but it's a starting point. After that you can add a Toolbar on the top of the Activity and the Navigation drawer on the left side. This is the method I would use :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some specific reason that you *only* want an app for Android, I would recommend something like Phonegap, which allows you to build the app for every conceivable platform for marginally more effort. Particularly if this is a commmercial app, there are few good reasons to specialize to only one platform.

In order to do this, you need some skills in Javascript/HTML5. Additionally, you should choose some type of structured framework (such as backbone.js, knockout.js, etc.) to organize your app.

Answer (score 0):

Expose your data of your web application through a REST api (There are other methods) and write a native android application.

Or you can just make the web application mobile friendly.